# Javascript - Get child element innerHTML onclick

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm creating a number of child elements in a wrapper tag:

```
// display prompts in html 
    function show_prompts(found_elements){
            var div = document.getElementById("prompts");

            // iterate through list of found words
            for (var i=0; i < found_elements.length; i++){

            // initialize child element
            var p = document.createElement('p');

            // creating specific ID for each child 
            identificator = 'variant'+[i];
            p.id = identificator;

            // filling child with text
            p.innerHTML = found_elements[i];

            p.addEventListener("click", function(){choose_prompt(identificator);});
            //p.setAttribute("onclick", "choose_prompt()");
            div.appendChild(p);
            }
    }
```

**The goal:**
That after clicking on one of the child elements in browser the function *choose_prompt* activates and makes some job using the innerHTML of a clicked element.

**The problem:** 
When clicking, *choose_prompt* determines the last iteration id for all of the elements. I know its because the *addEventListener* was called in the loop.

**Question:** 
How to pass the correct id to *choose_prompt* when clicking on exact child element?

I'm expected to cope with task without any jquery.
My second day with JS, so don't be strict.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS doesn't have block scope, thus all `identificator` bound is actually the last updated value.

Wrap it with a function call to create an isolated closure:

```
for (var i=0; i < found_elements.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
     // do your job here with i
  })(i)
}
```

Alternatively use `forEach` method, every iteration has its own scope:

```
found_elements.forEach(function(element, i) {
  // do your job here with i
});
```

Note: for the second approach, if `found_elements` is returned by dom api (`querySelectorAll`, `getElementsByTagName`, or other similar method), it's not a real array. Then you should call array method on it:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(found_elements, function(element, i) {
  // do your job here with i
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Spend quite enough time on it, huh. That solved the problem